# How to get orientation entanglement in network?

Tags: spinors, loop-quantum-gravity

Looking at this intuitive [description of spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_entanglement).

Is there a way to add something like this to a network graph. (e.g. the kinds of networks you get in LQG) or any kind of graph?

It looks like simple graphs can't model this as it needs the concept of lines that can't cross each other.

So what is the simplest kind of object that's an extension of graphs that can accomodate this?

Answer (score 0):

Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4719.

What follows is a very short, overly simplified cartoony picture.

Fermions can be encoded by spin network links with an open end. The spin of such links should be exactly $1/2$. The evaluation of the spin network functional on a gauge connection is a gauge invariant number, but the evaluation of the similar functional for a spin network with an open edge will give you an element of the spin-$1/2$ representation, that transforms nontrivially under gauge transformations. Specifically, it is acted on by $g(x)$ in the spin-$1/2$ representation, where $x$ is the spatial point where the open end of the loop is located.

To construct gauge invariant numbers, therefore, we have to take contractions of such spin network evaluations with spinors in spin-$1/2$ irrep, which are interpreted as the spin components of wavefunctions of fermions.